# Excel Function to Replace Substring

Tags: excel

I need to replace the values in cells that may contain certain values. Lets say I have the following values listed in the A column.

```
Trucking Inc.
New Truck Inc
ABV Trucking Inc, LLC
```

I want to be able to replace the following with a corresponding value. The following is a list contains in 2 columns. 1 Column is the From and the other is the To field.

```
      From      To
      " Inc."   ""
      " Inc"    ""
      " Inc, "  ""
      " LLC"    ""
```

The result should be:

```
Trucking
New Truck
ABV Trucking
```

Hope I am making sense here.

Comment: Have you thought about `Replace` `Ctrl + G` or `Substitute` function?

Comment: I use the following cell formula to find a specific set of test.

=IF(Q3="", 0, VLOOKUP(Q3,I$2:J$7, 2, FALSE))

Q3 is the value I am validating, this would be the data in the A column. The I column contains the From value and the J column contains the To value. The problem with this formula is it looks for the exact value. I need to find the substring.

Is a variation of this formula possible ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm making the same assumptions as Scott Holtzman - you probably want to use the SUBSITUTE function.

Example:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,C2)
```

This is the situation I am assuming for you:

[image: Your Situation I Think]

Just as an asside(lol pun): You should learn how to take screen shots and then edit them with MS paint - that will get alot more questions answered correctly for you (just for future reference):

Comment: For my needs this will definitely have to do. I just wish the From and To could be ranges like in the VLookup.

Answer (score 1):

I you are trying to do this in a macro then you can also try VBA Replace statement. It is much better than substitute function.

You can use following macro to help your cause:

```
Sub ChangeTerms()
Dim rows As Integer
Dim cellvalue As String
Dim Newcellvalue As String
rows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.rows.Count
For i = 1 To rows
cellvalue = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
Newcellvalue = Replace(cellvalue, " Inc.", "")
Newcellvalue = Replace(Newcellvalue, " Inc,", "")
Newcellvalue = Replace(Newcellvalue, " Inc", "")
Newcellvalue = Replace(Newcellvalue, " LLC", "")
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = Newcellvalue
Next i
End Sub
```

The heart of this macro is Replace function. If you need to know more about this function then please go through following resources:

http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-replace-function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5(v=vs.80).aspx